How to get a StadiumBorder for input fields - flutter
There is provision for a StadiumBorder as a shape which can used with buttons or DecorationBox and the like. But for an input field, there is only UnderlineInputBorder and OutlineInputBorder. How do you get that stadium border outline?

As of today, there is no out-of-the-box solution built into the framework, you would have to make yours.
Here is my implementation of a StadiumInputBorder. This should help:
@immutable
class StadiumInputBorder extends InputBorder {
  const StadiumInputBorder({
    super.borderSide = const BorderSide(),
  });

  @override
  bool get isOutline => true;

  @override
  StadiumInputBorder copyWith({BorderSide? borderSide}) {
    return StadiumInputBorder(borderSide: borderSide ?? this.borderSide);
  }

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.all(borderSide.width);

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => StadiumBorder(side: borderSide.scale(t));

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    final Radius radius = Radius.circular(rect.shortestSide / 2.0);
    final RRect borderRect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, radius);
    final RRect adjustedRect = borderRect.deflate(borderSide.strokeInset);
    return Path()..addRRect(adjustedRect);
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    final Radius radius = Radius.circular(rect.shortestSide / 2.0);
    return Path()..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, radius));
  }

  @override
  void paint(
    Canvas canvas,
    Rect rect, {
    double? gapStart,
    double gapExtent = 0.0,
    double gapPercentage = 0.0,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
  }) {
    switch (borderSide.style) {
      case BorderStyle.none:
        break;
      case BorderStyle.solid:
        final Radius radius = Radius.circular(rect.shortestSide / 2);
        final RRect borderRect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, radius);
        canvas.drawRRect(borderRect.inflate(borderSide.strokeOffset / 2), borderSide.toPaint());
    }
  }
}

